# Convergent Subsequences and continuity

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

Suppose f is a continuous function whose domain includes an interval [a,b]. Suppose that ${x_n}$ is a sequence of real numbers in [a,b] such that $f(x_n)$ converges to t. Prove there exists a sub sequence of $x_n$ that converges to a limit c in [a,b] for which $f(c)=t$.

I have pretty well no idea where to start with this. Any helpful theorems or tips?

Comment: Have you learned the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Bolzano-Weierstraß? Edit: Too slow. 

Comment: I assume we are allowed and yes we have learned it. I'm not sure I really know how to apply it though

Comment: Bolzano-Weierstrass says that every sequence has a convergent subsequence. It is also true that if a sequence is convergent to some limit c, then all of its subsequences converge to c. The proof follows from these two facts.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $[a,b]$, it is bounded. Hence by Bolzano-Weierstrass it has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ with
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=:c\in[a,b].$$
Furthermore by continuity of $f$ we have
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=f(c).$$
Note that $(f(x_{n_k}))$ is a subsequence of $(f(x_n))$, thus
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=t.$$
Hence $f(c)=t$.